# types of von Neumann subalgebras

Tags: operator-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

Let $N$ be a von Neumann subalgebra of the von Neumann algebra $M$. Is the type of $N$ at most the type of $M$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you refer to the main types I, II, III, then all inclusions are possible.

- $B(H)$ is type I and it contains all types.
- Any type II$_\infty$ algebra is of the form $M\otimes B(H)$, and so by embedding $I\otimes N$ you can get the subalgebra to be of any type.
- Any type III algebra $M$ satisfies $M\simeq M\otimes B(H)$, so again any type can be embedded as $I\otimes N$.

Comment: Adding to this answer, any subalgebra of a finite vNa is finite, so type $\mathrm{II}_1$ can only contain $\mathrm{II}_1$ and $\mathrm{I}_n$, $n < \infty$ subalgebras, but that’s more or less the only constraints.